# Docker : Battery historian - Pull access denied or require docker login

Tags: android, docker, performance-testing, battery, historian

I am following https://github.com/google/battery-historian

 I am trying to execute following commands on my Mac :

```
$ docker run -p 5665:9999 gcr.io/android-battery-historian/stable:3.0 --port 9999
```

But I am getting following error :

```
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/android-battery-historian/stable:3.0' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gcr.io/android-battery-historian/stable, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
```

Any leads appreciated.

[**UPDATE]:** Discussion thread for this problem on GitHub:
https://github.com/google/battery-historian/issues/125#issuecomment-353161947

Answer (score 0):

I also got similar issue , image might not be in the repo gcr.io/android-battery-historian/stable.

Try below image if its suitable for requirement.

```
docker run -d -p 9999:9999 bhaavan/battery-historian
```

https://hub.docker.com/r/bhaavan/battery-historian/

Comment: But this is privately managed library, not google battery historian, right?

Comment: i have seen the dockerfile for above image, https://github.com/bhaavanmerchant/battery-historian-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: @sanathmeti, It doesn't work for the Android 7.0 & up. It works below 7.0.

Comment: @Harsh4789 For now I am using the repository mentioned in answer. I have also posted the question on discussion thread https://github.com/google/battery-historian/issues/125#issuecomment-353161947